# Qt object ownership memory leak

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am reading an introduction book to Qt and I am writing this code:

**server.h**

```
class server : public QObject {
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    QTcpServer* chatServer;

public:
    explicit server(QObject *parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent) {}

//more code...
};

#endif // SERVER_H
```

Then the book suggests to create the object in this way:

```
chatServer = new QTcpServer();  //<-- ?)
chatServer->setMaxPendingConnections(10);
```

I have read online that Qt has an hierarchy because everything descends frm `QObject` and *the parent object will take care of the life of the children*. In this case, doesnt the code generate a memory leak?

Because `chatServer = new QTcpServer();` is equal to `chatServer = new QTcpServer(nullptr);` and so I am **not** specifying a parent! So there is nobody that takes care of the life of this object in the heap. Do I have to call the `delete` (or better use an unique_ptr ) to manage the memory?

Another fix that I'd use would be `chatServer = new QTcpServer(server);`. Would this be ok?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do QObject derived types need a parent QObject?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16784896/do-qobject-derived-types-need-a-parent-qobject)

Comment: ***Would this be ok?*** I am pretty sure you are correct. However I do have 1 question. Are threads involved in this code? The parent / child relationship does not work across threads.

Comment: In this particular case it might not be necessary to assign a parent to it, since `chatServer` should stay alive as long as the application runs. When you close the application the OS will wipe out the memory anyway. In the general case however `new ...(this)` should be used to do the work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this code is indeed all that's shown in your book, then you are correct. If you don't pass the parent to `QTcpServer` it won't be automatically deleted when your object is destroyed. You can also do that manually in the destructor or maybe even better - just don't use the pointer and use it directly (though you may need to use pointer if you, for example, decide to move the object to another thread).

Comment: could `unique_ptr` be a solution as well (if I really need a pointer)? By the way I was just reading the book, I also thing that a poiner is useless and a plain stack object would be good as well

Comment: Yes, it'd do if you also planning on transferring the ownership of the server (though not necessarily). If you just want to pass it around, then the raw pointer with proper `parent` would be better suited.

Answer (score 3):

This does indeed seem to be a memory leak. `chatServer` should have `this` as its parent so it will be automatically destroyed with the `server` object:

```
chatServer = new QTcpServer(this);
chatServer->setMaxPendingConnections(10);
// ... more code
```

Assuming that this happens inside a member function of the `server` class, this would parent the `QTcpServer` object to the `server` object.

If the book provides no specific reason to make the `QTcpServer` object dynamically allocated, it is probably not necessary. In that case, as Dan M. says, it is entirely possible to not use a pointer at all and simply have `QTcpServer chatServer`

Answer (score 0):

In the example you posted, you have to take care of the pointer for yourself.

But instead of calling `delete`, you may want to use the QObject's slot [`deleteLater`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#deleteLater).